# Changing setText through a UI thread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

On my `onCreate()` method I have the following code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_item_layout);
            final TextView cumItemRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CumItemRating);
            final String postText = "(No rating)";

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    cumItemRating.setText(postText);
                }
            });
        }
    };


    t.start();
    addListenerOnRatingBar();
    }
```

On the `addListenerOnRatingBar()` method, I want to be able to change the `cumItemRating.setText(postText)` and have it updated every time this method runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your TextView as a class/instance variable, initialize it in the onCreate like you are doing now. The TextView will be accessible from everywhere within the activity. You can just call cumItemRating.setText(postText) from there.